# Node js adding unwanted modules when I do npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to spin up a node service on my mac. When I run npm install in the folder where my node service is, it is installing modules which are not mentioned in my package.json. There are extra modules which I am not expecting and some modules that I expect are missing. What could be the reason? How does the node modules folder get created. Does it use any global set up? I am a newbie to nodejs and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: dependencies are often dependant on other packages - look up the modules you want on https://www.npmjs.com/ and you'll see what **they** require

Answer (score 5):

Well, it has been introduced with npm3 (https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v300-2015-06-25):

> Flat, flat, flat!
>
> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is
>   possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR
>   dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder
>   with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another
>   when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is something new that happened in the newest version of `npm`.

If I'm not mistaken, it's installing all the dependencies `flat` instead of nested inside of whichever module that needs it.