# npm install creates inordinate amount of dependencies in node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

This started happening just recently, but every time I run `npm install` I end up getting dozens of node modules beyond what's listed in `package.json`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520581/node-js-adding-unwanted-modules-when-i-do-npm-install) shows that this is a new feature of `npm 3` where the dependencies are being "flattened" instead of nested. However, I don't want to look at a bazillion modules every time I venture into the folder. **Is there any way I can disable this setting?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that cannot be disabled.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10079

> > is there anyway that I can force npm@3 to install new package for me, but old way? So without calculating project-wise tree. I just want the new package to be placed in node_modules with its dependencies in its node_modules?
>
> No. The new installer is pretty much a complete rewrite, and while there is some special-case code to install packages into siloed subdirectories, that's only available when doing global installs, to simplify packaging and managing shared tools.